# Confusion on a integration problem

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

Is it correct to ask to evaluate the integral:

> $$\int_{-1}^{1}\dfrac{1}{x}dx$$

The function $f(x)=\dfrac{1}{x}$ is not defined at $0$.

Comment: You may have a look at the examples for Cauchy principal values of integrals (yours is the first):
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value#Examples

Comment: The value of the function at a single point does not affect the value of the integral.

Comment: Since $\frac 1x$ is unbounded, it is not Riemann integrable. But the principal value exists.

Answer (score 1):

Since $f$ is unbounded, it is nt Riemann integrable.

You can ask if the integral exists as an improper integral. This means that both
$$
\lim_{\epsilon\to0^-}\int_{-1}^{\epsilon}\frac{dx}{x}\quad \text{and} \quad\lim_{\epsilon\to0^+}\int_{\epsilon}^1\frac{dx}{x}
$$
must exists, which is not the case.

Finally, you might consider the principal value, which is defined as
$$
\operatorname{p.v}\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{dx}{x}=\lim_{\epsilon\to0^+}\Bigl(\int_{-1}^{-\epsilon}+\int_{\epsilon}^1\Bigr)\frac{dx}{x}=0.
$$